# What does "${!var}" mean in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, variable-expansion

I have a code block with below condition, not sure what exactly it does.

```
$var = "${args}_Some_Text"
if [ "${!var}"  == '' ];then
     echo "$var is not defined !!!"
fi
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is called variable indirect expansion.

```
$ hello="this is some text"   # we set $hello
$ var="hello"                 # $var is "hello"
$ echo "${!var}"              # we print the variable linked by $var's content
this is some text
```

As you see, it is a way to define "variable variables". That is, to use variables whose content is the name of another variable.

From [Bash Reference Manual → 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), and *parameter* is not a *nameref*, it introduces a level of variable indirection. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of *parameter* itself. This is known as indirect expansion. If parameter is a *nameref*, this expands to the name of the variable referenced by parameter instead of performing the complete indirect expansion. The exceptions to this are the expansions of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below. The exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to introduce indirection.