# Setting a Variable in an if loop in Bash

Tags: bash

```
  animal_name=""

  if [[ -z "${!animal_name// }" ]]; then
   animal_name="doggo"
  fi
    
 echo sudo chmod ...... ${!animal_name}
```

Is there any way to reference a variable in bash?

Comment: Describe what you want to do and what the desired output is.

Comment: @Cyrus in the case the variable does not exist, I was the animal_name to be set to "doggo". However, it always ends up being blank when I try to echo

Comment: Set default content if variable is empty: `echo "${animal_name:=doggo}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditch the "{}"

```
animal_name=""
if [[ -z "$animal_name" ]]; then
    animal_name="doggo"
fi

sudo chmod {flag} $animal_name
```

Comment: sorry made an edit. I have more thing happening in the echo. Can i still use this?

Comment: Sure thing. :)
I'll edit the answer to show your use case

Comment: One question though - why use the echo?
Are you trying to execute chmod or print out the whole "chmod {flag} $animal_name"?

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in line 3 (or 2, depending on how you look at it.)

```sh
animal_name=""

if [[ -z "${!animal_name// }" ]]; then # Error: event not found: animal_name//
animal_name="doggo"
fi

echo sudo chmod ...... $animal_name
```

The fix that I found was to remove the 2 slashes in `"${!animal_name// }"` and that worked for me.

Comment: Edited to include the `chmod ......`. Could you provide some more background? like do you have a file/executable named doggo? what's the purpose of `sudo chmod ...... {!animal_name}`?

Comment: oh i think im getting this mixed up with javascript... do you know what {!animal_name} means when I include {! }?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to make sure the variable has *some* value, you can use defaults.

```
echo sudo chmod ...... ${animal_name:-doggo}
```

This will use `doggo` is `animal_name` is empty, but will leave it empty.

```
$: animal_name=
$: echo sudo chmod ...... ${animal_name:-doggo}
sudo chmod ...... doggo
$: echo "[$animal_name]" # still empty
[]
$: animal_name=bob
$: echo sudo chmod ...... ${animal_name:-doggo} # doesn't change is already set
sudo chmod ...... bob
```

If you want `animal_name` to ALWAYS default to `doggo` thereafter, use `=` instead of `-` and it will assign it as well if it's empty.

```
echo sudo chmod ...... ${animal_name:=doggo}
```

so:

```
$: animal_name=
$: echo sudo chmod ...... ${animal_name:=doggo}
sudo chmod ...... doggo
$: echo "[$animal_name]" # this time it was set
[doggo]
$: animal_name=bob
$: echo sudo chmod ...... ${animal_name:=doggo} # doesn't change if already set
sudo chmod ...... bob
```

Comment: Heck, this is the answer Cyrus gave in the comments *yesterday*, lol...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you mean `indirection`? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928492/what-does-var-mean-in-shell-script) may help.

```sh
animal_name=""
doggo="I am doggo!"
if [[ -z "${animal_name}" ]]; then
  animal_name="doggo"
fi

echo sudo chmod ...... ${!animal_name}
```

The `${!animal_name}` reference the value of `doggo`, so the output is:

```
sudo chmod ...... I am doggo!
```