# bash/shell script: evaluating a hashmap key to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Im no bash/shell script expert...what im trying to do the is following: im using array variables as keys to a hashmap. when i iterate over the keys of the hash map i want to evaluate them to the actual array, iterate over the array and print the values in that array out.

```
arr1=(A B)
arr2=(C D)

declare -A arrmap
arrmap=(
    [arr1]="array 1"
    [arr2]="array 2"
)

for k in "${!arrmap[@]}";
do  
    for f in "${k[@]}";
        do echo "$k: $f";
    done
done
```

This prints out:

```
arr2: arr2
arr1: arr1
```

but what i would like to see is:

```
A: array 1
B: array 1
C: array 2
D: array 2
```

EDIT: think i was able to figure it out:

```
for k in "${!arrmap[@]}"; do  
    eval a=\( \${${k}[@]} \)
    for f in "${a[@]}"; do 
        echo "$k: $f";
    done
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is that if you find yourself wanting to use `eval`, you're doing something wrong. In this case, a `nameref` is what you need instead.

[Documentation for `declare -n`:](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-declare)

> Give each name the nameref attribute, making it a name reference to another variable. That other variable is defined by the value of name. All references, assignments, and attribute modifications to name, except for those using or changing the -n attribute itself, are performed on the variable referenced by name’s value.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

arr1=(A B)
arr2=(C D)

declare -A arrmap=(
    [arr1]="array 1"
    [arr2]="array 2"
)

for k in "${!arrmap[@]}";
do
    declare -n arr="$k"
    for f in "${arr[@]}"; do
        echo "$f: ${arrmap[$k]}"
    done
done
```

will output

```
C: array 2
D: array 2
A: array 1
B: array 1
```

(Order may vary; hash tables don't iterate over elements in a set predictable order)

Answer (score 1):

You can use indirect expansion (`${!var}`) to do what you want without `eval`:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

arr1=(A B)
arr2=(C D)

declare -A arrmap
arrmap=(
    [arr1]='array 1'
    [arr2]='array 2'
)

for k in "${!arrmap[@]}"; do  
    ref="$k[@]"
    for f in "${!ref}"; do
        printf "%s: %s\n" "$f" "${arrmap[$k]}"
    done
done
```

- This code works with Bash version 4.0 (tested), and should work with all later versions.  It won't work with older versions because support for associative arrays was introduced in Bash 4.0.  Support for namerefs was added in Bash 4.3.
- See [What does "${!var}" mean in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40928492/4154375) and [BashFAQ/006 (How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for information about indirect expansion in Bash.
- The code causes a few harmless [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) warnings.  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) doesn't handle indirect expansion well.
- Note that, in common with (the much more maligned) `eval`, both indirect variable expansion and namerefs are vulnerable to [Code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).  This code should be safe, assuming that the contents of `arrmap` are controlled.
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I replaced `echo` with `printf`.