# Searching multiple arrays for values and returning the array name

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix

I have an requirement wherein I have multiple values in a file and 8 arrays containing numeric values.
For example:

```
Array1=(1 2 3 4 5) 
Array2=(6 7 8 9 10)
```

File has values 3 and 9. So it should return Array1 in first case and Array2 in second case.
Also I want to store the result in another file having value followed by array name that contains that value.

Unable to find any solution.

Comment: Can you redefine your question? Problem description and statement seems confusing.

Comment: Please add a desired output and also what have you tried so far.

Comment: This sounds a little complex for bash. You need something to associate a name with an array, such as a tuple or a class, or a map/dict or multidimensional array, and I don't think bash supports any of those. You can really twist the parameter expansion syntax (`${...}`) to emulate them, but that is undecipherable torture. Awk might be powerful enough, but if not Python, Perl, and many other languages definitely would work.

Comment: @JohnBayko _You need something to associate a name with an array_: Recent `bash` supports namerefs. And `grep` suffices for the rest (see my answer).

Comment: Hi @VrajBhatt, Thanks for replying back. I'll be short and precise. I have 2 arrays (listed in question) and a separate text file having numeric values in it say 3  9. I want to search these values (3  9) in those arrays and return the array name which has those values present in it. The output file should contain  2 lines in it. 1st line (3 Array1) 2nd line (9 Array2) i.e value and the array name in which it is present.

Comment: Hi @Jetchisel, Thanks for replying back. But am blocked. Don't know how to start with the solution. Its just that I have declared arrays :) New to stackoverflow so unsure about proper formatting but the desired output can be found in my above comment. Bash should be able to create an output file having 2 lines in it. 1st line (3 Array1) 2nd line (9 Array2) i.e value and the array name in which it is present.

Answer (score 2):

If your bash is recent enough:

```
for a in Array1 Array2; do
  declare -n arr="$a"
  grep -oFf <(printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}") file && printf '(in %s)\n' "$a"
done > results
```

Explanation:

- `declare -n arr="$a"` declares a nameref, a kind of alias. If executed when the value of `a` is `Array1`, `arr` becomes a synonym of `Array1`.
- `printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"` prints each entry in array `arr` on a separate line.
- `<(command)` is a process substitution, the command is run and its output is seen as a file by the environment. In our case the content of the array is considered as a file with one entry per line.
- `grep -oFf file1 file2` takes the patterns to search in `file1` (`-f file1`), in our case in the process substitution, considers them as plain text strings, not regular expressions (`-F`), and outputs only the matched parts (`-o`).
- `grep` exits with status 0 if a pattern matched, else it exits with a non-zero status. As the 0 exit status is considered as boolean true, the `printf '(in %s)\n'` that prints the array name is executed only if `grep` found one of the patterns in `file`, thanks to the `&&` operator (AND).

Demo (output prefixed with `-|` ):

```
printf '3\n9\n15\n' > file
Array1=(1 2 3 4 5)
Array2=(6 7 8 9 10)
Array3=(a b c d e)
for a in Array1 Array2 Array3; do
  declare -n arr="$a"
  grep -oFf <(printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}") file && printf '(in %s)\n' "$a"
done > results
cat results
-| 3
-| 1
-| 5
-| (in Array1)
-| 9
-| (in Array2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

Array1=(1 2 3 4 5) 
Array2=(6 7 8 9 10) 

while read -r val || [[ -n $val ]]; do
    for arr in Array1 Array2; do
        aref="${arr}[@]"
        for elem in "${!aref}"; do
            if [[ $elem == "$val" ]]; then
                printf '%s %s\n' "$val" "$arr"
                break
            fi
        done
    done
done <file
```

- This should work on any non-ancient version of Bash.  (I tested it with Bash 3.2 (released in 2006).)
- The `|| [[ -n $val ]]` is to support input files that don't have the last line properly terminated.  See the [My text files are broken! They lack their final newlines!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#My_text_files_are_broken.21__They_lack_their_final_newlines.21) section of [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).
- See [What does "${!var}" mean in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40928492/4154375) for an explanation of `${!aref}`.
- `echo` doesn't work reliably for variable data so I used `printf` to produce the output.  See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).

Comment: Hi PJH, Thanks for replying .. will it work in case of shell.   My script starts with #!/bin/sh. Also I have 4.4.20 version Bash installed in my server.

Comment: @NitinKumar, it will work if `/bin/sh` is really Bash.  If `/bin/sh` is `dash` then nothing will work because `dash` does not support arrays.  If your code depends on Bash-specific features, including arrays, it should start with `#! ...bash...`.  Run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on your code to find features that are not guaranteed to be supported by `/bin/sh` (and many other common problems with shell code).  The code in the answer should work with *any* version of Bash since 3.0.  I tested it on 3.2 and 5.2.

Comment: @NitinKumar, see [Difference between sh and Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5725296/4154375).